# Contenteditable/Jquery/Ajax/PHP/mysql - Cannot recognize $_GET variable from URL

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, contenteditable

I am trying to build a site where you can modify and update a mysql database directly using contenteditable in combination with jquery, ajax and PHP.  The code captures data via $_POST['content'] with some jquery/ajax to load a php file (save.php).  The save.php file runs a mysql UPDATE to update the database using the $_POST['content'] information entered by contenteditable provided by the user.

In the save.php file I use a unique ID to identify which row must be updated.  This ID is accessible via URL.  I try to capture the ID by $_GET['id'] and convert this to $var_id=$_GET['id'].  My problem is that when I try to access the id ($var_id) variable obtained from the URL

ex. http://www.website.org/selectedvariant.php?id=100

the $var_id is not recognized in the save.php file and the mysql UPDATE does not work.  I know that this a problem with accessing the $var_id variable because when I manually put the variable_id='100' it works properly.  Indicating that the save.php file is just not getting a proper value for the $var_id variable.

Any help to resolve this long-standing challenge would be greatly appreciated!

save.php

```
<?php mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$content=mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['content']); //gets the posted content
$var_id=$_GET['id'];

$sql="update table_list set column='$content' where id='$var_id'";
if (mysql_query($sql))
{echo 1;
}
?>
```

other.php file (only relevant (i think?)) info

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#save").click(function (e) {         
        var content = $('#editable').html();    

        $.ajax({
            url: 'save.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
            content: content
            },
```

Most of this code has been pulled from the tutorial:

http://gazpo.com/2011/09/contenteditable/

Thanks,
Ron

Comment: Ajax only sending `content` by `POST` method. `save.php` does not really receive `id` as querystring param.

Answer (score 2):

When you make the ajax call, you need to pass both `content` and `id` via some method (get or post). In your code, you are sending `content` data via `POST` method to `save.php`. `ID` is not being sent to your php script anyhow. Change your `url` params to -

```
url:'save.php?id='+WhatYouHaveInHand
```

Comment: Works!  Placed url:'save.php?id='+<?php echo $var_id; ?> for those interested.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the ID anywhere. This is the issue.

For an AJAX POST call to also return GET parameters, the parameters must be in the query string. So, for instance, if you wanted to pass a random ID, you would do

```
$("#save").click(function (e) {         
    var content = $('#editable').html();    
    var randomID = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'save.php?id='+randomID,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
        content: content
        },this:
```

You will obviously need to adapt this to provide a real ID. However, the idea is there.